# QGIS plugin (or other method) to create multi-layer buffer simultaneousely based on parameter input?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I'm looking for a way to create buffers around objects from more than one layer at the same time, with specific buffer distances, and possibly rendering live the global buffer (resulting of all the merged buffers).

An input box would ask which layer needs to be considered (selected objects or not...), and for each, the buffer required.

A result layer could then be saved for any parameter combination chosen.

The goal is to obtain an instant view of what land is available with a given set of constraints from different layers.

Comment: You should reorganize your question in a simpler way : First your question (ex : How to create buffer on multiple layer simultaneously OR Using processing tools on multiple layers simultaneously) Then after your various comments. The way you wrote it, it looks quite complicated to see what you need exactly and your question looks unfocused on one subject.